# Android studio: unsupported class file version 52.0 after including a java 8 module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, unsupported-class-version

I had a project with no errors in Android studio but when I included some new jar files I had the following `parse error: Error:unsupported class file version 52.0`.

Now, I know that at least some of those libraries are compiled with java 8 and I tried to run the code which uses them with Eclipse and it works. So i checked what version of Java compiler my Eclipse was using and I did it going in help->eclipse installation->configuration and looking for java_home. Then I changed my jdk location in Android Studio in the project structure menu by using the same folder as Eclipse. I still have the same error.

So I added the following code tu my build.gradle at module level

```
buildscript {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

but it didn't fix the issue.
I also tried with VERSION_1_7 just for the records.

So If I'm now using java 8 why is Android Studio not compiling while Eclipse does it? Maybe I need to do something else to be using jdk 1.8 in Android Studio.

If you need further log information please tell me where to find them, because when I go for help->show log in explorer->log.txt seems like there is nothing related to these java errors.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: Can you please give me a little description of what you linked and why?

Anyway it says: "The Jack toolchain is deprecated, as per this announcement. You may continue to use it, or try the latest preview version of Android Studio to use improved support for Java 8 language features built into the default toolchain." and I'm actually using the last stable version.

Comment: as per that link, you can't use java8 in stable. you need to go to the canary build if you want any java8